# node.js - move the res.send() outside of function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

currently what i have is:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    var oo = require('/test.js');
    oo(connection, function (e, result) {
        res.end(result);
    });
}).listen(80);
```

what i would like to do is

```
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
    var oo = require('/test.js');
    oo(connection, function (e, result) {});
    res.end(result);
}).listen(80);
```

but this does not work.

the idea is to move

```
res.end(result);
```

right above

```
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? From the looks of it, `oo` is an asynchronous function. If you try to do that, the response will be ended before `oo` can get the result.

Comment: so what do you do exactly. to get the output out of that function ?

Comment: No need to to anything else. The first code snippet will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you want to do so, please read [about async and sync code](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node), *not best article, - but you can find many of them*, but I have a solution for you.

Before you go, install [Fibers package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers):

```
npm install fibers
```

Solution:

```
var Future = require('fibers/future');
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
   fut = new Future();
   res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
   var oo = require('/test.js');
   oo(connection, function (e, result) {
      fut.return(result);
   });
   res.end(fut.wait());

}).listen(80);
```

And read about [JS Conventions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp), please.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be moved outside the callback function, because in such case it would be executed before callback, which I guess generates an output to `res`. This result won't be sent, because you closed `res` before.